# extracting nested different types of archives from different folders

Tags: linux, bash, shell, archiving

I have got an archive of many fonts but i have troubble extracting them all into one folder. i tried to write a long script for 3 hours now, it somehow breaks on a path issue. i tried piping like find `. -name *.zip|unzip -d ~/fonts` but it doesnt work. i changed so much in the script i wrote, that it is [not really presentable](http://pastebin.org/818297) :(.

each fontfile is supposedly (i didnt check all, there are really many) inside a rar archive which together with a readme is in a zip archive which together with another readme is in each its own folder. can this be done in one line?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the one line like this
find . -name "*.zip" | xargs unzip -d ~/fonts

Comment: Archive:  ./FONT1-TYPO/t-1.zip
caution: filename not matched:  ./FONT2-TYPO/t-2.zip caution: filename not matched:  ./FONT2-TYPO/t-2.zip

Comment: if i try "unzip -d ~/fonts ./FONT1-TYPO/t-1.zip", then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
find . -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -d ~/fonts {} \;
```